# Camel continously sending messages

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

I am using Camel for integration. I have a use case where Camel should transfer 1 message from one queue to another, but it is continuously sending same message to the queue. Please look into following routes I have:

[ProducerTemplate](https://zgrepcode.com/apache-camel/2.23.1/org/apache/camel/producertemplate.java) is creating message in following manner:

```
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct://input", "This is a test message: ");
```

I have a route which transfers message from direct component to rabbitmq queue.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct://input")
                .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/test_ip?queue=task_queue&routingKey=test_task" +
                                "&autoAck=true&durable=true&username=guest&password=guest&autoDelete=false&exchangePattern=InOut")

            }
```

Then I have a route which transfers message from `task_queue` to `out_queue`

```
 public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/test_ip?queue=task_queue&username=guest&routingKey=test_task&password=guest" +
                        "&autoAck=true&durable=true&exchangeType=direct&autoDelete=false&exchangePattern=InOut")
        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                exchange.setOut(exchange.getIn());
                                Message m = exchange.getOut();
                                org.apache.camel.TypeConverter tc = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter();
                                String strValue = tc.convertTo(String.class, m.getBody());
                                System.out.println("[[task_queue -- out_queue]]: "  + strValue);
                            }
                        })
                       .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/test_op?queue=out_queue&routingKey=test_out&username=guest&password=guest" +
                            "&autoAck=true&durable=true&exchangeType=direct&autoDelete=false&exchangePattern=InOut");
            }
```

I have only these 2 routes in my program, nothing else. Now when I run it, I get the following output:

```
[[task_queue -- out_queue]]: This is a test message: 
[[task_queue -- out_queue]]: This is a test message: 
[[task_queue -- out_queue]]: This is a test message: 
[[task_queue -- out_queue]]: This is a test message: 
[[task_queue -- out_queue]]: This is a test message: 
.
.
(continuous stream till I kill program)
```

The output I have shown above is not the expected one. It should NOT keep printing the out message many times, but it should out it just once. It means 1 message is getting processed (and transferred to `out_queue`) again and again.

Can anyone suggest the reason? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing obvious. Have you tried replacing the RabbitMQ queues with seda queues so you can see if the problem relates to Camel to RabbitMQ?

Comment: It is related to RabbitMq. Because I tried this with other components, and this problem didn't replicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread solved my problem: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-rabbitmq-routing-issue-td5744371.html